# Reading values from Python Dictionary in Simulink Matlab Function Block

Tags: python, matlab, dictionary, simulink

I have problems reading values from a Python dictionary in to Simulink using a Matlab Function Block.
The Python Dictionary is stored in the Matlab Base Workspace. It contains Data delivered by a MQTT-Broker. The keys of the dicitonary are the topics and the values are the payload of specific MQTT-Messages. Because all of the topics contain slashes it is not possible to convert the Python-Dictionary to a Matlab struct. Now I want to read the values of defined topics to my Simulink Model. Unfortunately the syntax that works in Matlab doesn't work in the Simulink Matlab Function Block.

In Matlab I am able to read data from the dictionary by using the key in curly brackets:

```
MQTTValue = PythonDict{'level1/level2/value'}
```

To read the payload of the same MQTT-Message to Simulink i used the following code in a Matlab Function Block:

```
function MQTTValue  = fcn()

coder.extrinsic('evalin');

PythonDict = evalin('base','PythonDict');

MQTTValue = PythonDict{'level1/level2/value'};
```

However I get the following error when running the Model:

`Brace indexing is not supported for variables of this type.`

I expected to be able to read the value from the dictionary just like in Matlab.

Also when trying to read multiple entries of the dictionary using a cell-Array called TopicArray and the following code Matlab crashes completely during the compilation of the model:

```
function MQTTValues  = fcn(TopicArray)

coder.extrinsic('evalin');

MQTTValues = zeros(1,length(TopicArray));

PythonDict = evalin('base','PythonDict');

for i = 1:length(MQTTValues)
    MQTTValues(i) = PythonDict{TopicArray{i}};
end
```